# Double integral using scipy.integrate.dblquad

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to do a double integral using scipy.integrate.dblquad. The code is as below:

```
    from scipy.integrate import dblquad
    import numpy as np
    def integrand(x, y, a, b):
    return a*x**2 + b*y**3
    def low_y(x):
        0
    def up_y(x):
        1-2*x
    a = 1.0
    b = 1.0
    area = dblquad(integrand, 0, np.Inf, low_y, up_y, args=(a,b), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08)
    print area
```

But I am getting an error like `TypeError: a float is required` and error is indicating the second last line of the code. Any solutions please?

Comment: you're missing `return` in both of the low\up functions

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing out this. The code runs now.

Answer (score 1):

We should always test each piece of our program when a problem is encountered.  In this case, what happens when we run `low_y(1.0)` or `up_y(1.0)`?  What should happen?  Do we see the error?

For simple boundary functions such as this you may want to use a `lambda` function instead, though this is largely a matter of taste.  Here you could write your integral as

```
area = dblquad(integrand, 0, np.Inf, lambda x : 0, lambda x : 1-2*x, args=(a,b), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08)
```

Note: This may just be a test case, but this function does not have a finite volume when integrated to infinity!

Comment: If I change the code & x limit as `area = dblquad(integrand, 0, 4, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1-2*x, args=(a,b), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08)` it gives me finite value `(-445.59999999999997, 4.948156561840544e-12)`. If I make the upper x limit as infinity it doesn't converge. That's fine. Depending upon the problem I can make the upper limit to some large value. But I want to keep the y limit as defined functions outside the dblquad step.

Comment: So, when I use `area = dblquad(integrand, 0, 4, lambda x: low_y, lambda x: up_y, args=(a,b), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08)` it again shows the same old error `TypeError: a float is required`.

Comment: @Chicku: `lambda x: low_y` is a function which returns `low_y`, which is a function, not a float.  And as this answer tried to to get you to notice, your `low_y` and `up_y` functions don't work.

Comment: @DSM: Yes. I forgot to add `return` in both `low_y` & `up_y`. Now the original code is running fine. Thanks :)